# How do you get the Master Assassin Armour?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

While i was playing, in Memory Sequence 3 or 4 (It was quite early, i still hadn't gotten an entire set of the most basic Armour) and after completing a mission i got from promoting an assassin to be my last den master (it was one about a rich man paying merchants for the Templars, he claims he was corrupted by them) as soon as i completed the mission i suddenly got the Master Assassin Armour.

I am wondering, did i get this as a bug or did i get the Armour as a result of setting up my last Den Master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.

The [Master Assassin Armor](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Assassin_Armor) set is obtained - exactly as you described - by giving every Assassin Den a Master Assassin.

Answer (score 0):

I was just replaying it now and got the master assasin armor despite only having two master assasins assigned to a den. It took me a while to even notice my health had more than doubled (I was just running around town buying everything and leveling my assassins). Since I also completed the rich man working for the templars quest, I'm guessing this was the trigger. First I just thought I got the armor because of a glitch, since it's end game armor in the beginning of the game.